# Connection to localhost:5432 refused on nifi UI

Tags: postgresql, apache-nifi

- Currently running nifi and postgresql on docker compose.
  I have a problem setting up the DBCPConnectionPool controller. I keep getting the error message below
  [image]
- Below is my Configuration for DBCPConnectionPool
  [image]
- How can I possibly solve this problem? Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Not an expert on Nifi or postgres, but I think the issue is, you are trying to connect via "localhost", but you should be using "host.docker.internal" instead.

Or if you have named your service in dockercompose - like mynifi and mypostgres, then you can try using that name for communication between containers - like from mynifi container, you can talk to postgres using mypostgres:5432

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I used romote host instead. It worked.
Don't know why it cannot connect to postgresql via localhost.

Comment: Your answer gives an alternative, but no explanation to the direct question: "Why is it not working". Therefore the answer is not optimal in this situation.